# How do I change nightly about:home to firefoxs' one

Tags: windows-8, firefox

I am using nightly regularly but since firefox changed their `about:home` to the animated page I've taken fond to it and want to use *that* page on nightly.

I suppose I can just change the home page but what do I change it to?

Answer (score 1):

On about:home, press ctrl+U (this shows you the source of the page). Then look at the title bar. In order to get the xhtml file, you would need to extract the .ja file. This page is of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I wans't clear enough, Can I change nightly about:home to firefox one without having firefox explicitly installed?

Comment: The about:home page resides on your computer which is why one can see the page without being connected to the internet. So you would have the normal version of firefox installed.

Comment: Ok so now I have to extract omni.ja!?

Comment: Yes. This page may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29

Comment: If you want to edit it into the question complete with the explanation it will be great. (Don't want to make a radical change edit